# Float64Array are crossplatform?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have the following code:

```
a = new Float64Array([num])
b = new Uint8Array(a.buffer)
```

I noticed that the elements of *b* are little endian and represents the Float64 number using IEEE754.

Is this representation standardized and the same in every browser/js-engine? Or will it change from a browser to other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the behavior is standardized, not the representation.

Comment: Can't you consider the value returned from a call to b[0] a behavior?

Comment: if you use dataview, you can still choose between little and big endian